# Suggest Box with Calculated tables

Tags: google-app-maker

I am trying to use a SuggestBox on a Calculated Table. I am able to see the values, however the results are not filtered based on the value I type in the field. Is there a limitation with its used on Calculated tables?

Thanks,
Maria.

Answer (score 0):

Currently App Maker filters data automatically when SuggestBox in "Use specified field as value" mode only.

In "Use whole record as value" mode query parameter supplied to the Calculated Model script has startsWith filter for the Field which the script should respect.

This filter can be mapped to underlying DB query or processed in code like:

```
var records = ...records generation code...;
var prefix = query.filters.FIELDNAME._startsWith.toLowerCase();
return records.filter(function(record){
  return record.FIELDNAME.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf(prefix, 0) === 0;
});
```

It is so for performance reasons, but I'll consider to improve documentation and add an automatic results filtering option.